# eclipse - Output

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I have a Java program - which uses genetic algorithms - in which I generate a random binary string.  From here, I calculate the fitness of said string and print the fitness to the output console.

I am now attempting to display the string, but I am having trouble doing this.  My intention is to display the string, then mutate it by changing one gene, and then recalculate the fitness.  However, whenever I try to print the string, I receive this in the output window:

```
Individual@23fc4bec //FYI: Class name is 'Individual'
```

This is my code - in the `main` method - so far:

```
Individual newIndi = new Individual();

System.out.println(newIndi.fitness);

System.out.print(newIndi);
```

The problem occurs on the last line - I have also attempted the following:

```
System.out.print(newIndi.toString());
```

but this still produces a similar result.

Comment: Thank you so much to all who have taken the time and effort to provide answers; unfortunately, however, it appears that everybody has focussed on the `toString()` method.  I may not have been very clear, so apologies for that - I only tried the `toString()` method because the first `System.out.print(newIndi);` did not produce my desired result.  Is there a way to print the value of `newIndi` without using the `toString()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the toString method in you `Individual`-Class.

```
public class Individual {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      // output
    }
}
```

Note: eclipse can generate you some basic toString() methode for your class (Source > Generate toString()).

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to print a private variable in another class, overriding the toString method in your Individual class would allow you to return that variable (as others have said).  Simply create a toString method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return whateverYourVarNameIs;
}
```

Trying to just print the object name will, by default, call the toString method, which will return the memory location of the object if you do not override it.

Another idea might simply be to create a new method.

```
public String getGenes()
{
    return whateverYourVarNameIs;
}
```

and do

```
System.out.println(whateverYourVarNameIs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `toString` method is implemented by `java.lang.Object`, and returns the class name of the object followed by its hashCode. If you want to print something other than that, you need to override toString and make it return what you desire.

Note that `System.out.print(newIndi);` calls the `toString` method on `newIndi`. You don't need to explicitely call `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the toString() method in Individual to actually output the content of the class. The default Object toString() will return what you have above.

Answer (score 0):

your Individual Class should reimplement the toString method, if you want to do it this way, or else the it will print the Java Reference (as you see). System.out.println(newIndi) calls the toString method.